# error 50 con SQLEXPRESS y base de datos .mdf c#

Tags: c#, sql, crud, connection, sql-server-express

hice una aplicación con `c#` para escritorio y he usado `SQLExpress` para sustituir `Access` (la aplicación es para uso local).

Tengo una Base de Datos `.mdf` y cuando hago pruebas e incluso ejecuto la aplicación en mi equipo lee y graba bien, pero quise mover a otro equipo esa carpeta y al tratar de leer la base de datos me manda mensaje con error **50** y **52**. La pregunta es:

¿qué necesito para que mi aplicación pueda moverla y funcione la base de datos?

En mi ConnectionString tengo:

```
@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLocalDB;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\MiDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

Gracias!

Comment: Necesitas instalar sql express en el cliente...

Comment: Viendo la cadena de conexión, eso no es `SQL EXPRESS`, porque con un servidor express no trabajas contra un mdb.....sino localDb. Similar pero diferente. Te dejo un enlace que te puede ayudar bastante. [Que es localDb](https://www.jasoft.org/Blog/post/que-es-sql-server-localdb-como-instalarlo-usarlo-y-actualizarlo)